# App crashed when enter command: npm run dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, nodemon

[Full image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg3bp.png)

I'm new in learning React, today, I have trouble as below and I can't fix it, please help me. Below is the error

[image]

Comment: It would be really great, if you could post the content of your images as text!

Comment: Post full errror log please

Comment: if i convert that img to text, it's too long to read ~~ i posted the full img of error

Answer (score -1):

**Package.json**

```
"dev": "nodemon --watch *.js --exec 'node --harmony api.js'",
 change to:
"dev": "nodemon --watch *.js -x npm run start",
```

**and then ‘npm run dev’ start a dev serve normally.**

Comment: `"dev": "nodemon server.js -w server.js -w routes.js -w config/router.config.js -w next.config.js -w .env "`
This is my "dev" line, how can i edit it

Comment: It depends on which file needs to be run . In above only reactjs server and express server needs to be started.